# Android drawing graph using graph view

Tags: android, graph

I have a graph that is not a real time graph, i want to add the x-axis and y-axis from the data that i have.

```
GraphView line_graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph3);

    LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> line_series =
            new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>(new DataPoint[] {
                    new DataPoint(0, 0),
                    new DataPoint(1, 5),
                    new DataPoint(2, 3),
                    new DataPoint(3, 2),
                    new DataPoint(4, 6)
            });
    line_graph.addSeries(line_series);
```

i was just testing the graph with the above points. And now i have an array received from database using JSON, i want to use them as the x-axis data and y-axis data. Just like array[oddNumber] as x-axis data, array[evenNumber] as y-axis data. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get your JSON data and convert it in Integer array like xAxis and yAxis.

Now do like this,

```
Integer[] xAxis = new Integer[]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    Integer[] yAxis = new Integer[]{0, 5, 3, 2, 6};

    GraphView line_graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph3);

    DataPoint[] dataPoints = new DataPoint[xAxis.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < xAxis.length; i++)
    {
        dataPoints[i] = new DataPoint(xAxis[i],yAxis[i]);
    }

    LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> line_series =
            new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>(dataPoints);

    line_graph.addSeries(line_series);
```

Note: Length of xAxis and yAxis array must be same.

Comment: it works but the it is not a line, i mean the same point can form two lines, can you help arrange them in order? As the point is from database, which means data may not be in ascending order

Comment: I cannot understand. What you exactly want?

Comment: the line is crossing, as the data in x axis is not in ascending order, i want to arrange all data in x axis in ascending